# Custom MVC Routes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

So I just got to routes on my first big MVC app and its giving me a headache.

All `/Category/Subcategory` goes to the `ProductController.Index(string category, string subcategory)`. If I don't specify a Subcategory it will show me all items in the Category (Fords, Audis etc)

If I have my routes like this, url `/Home/About` goes to `Product/Index` with parameters: `Category=Home, Subcategory=About`.

If I move the default to the top, url `/Car/Ford` does not go anywhere since I don't have a `CarController` (I don't want a controller for every category.)

I'd really like to not have another segment like /store/Car/Ford..

Do I need to create a route for every "main" Category and hardcode the name?
Help me solve this problem!

```
// http://localhost/Car/Ford (note: Car can be replaced by bike, plan, boat etc.)
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "AllProductsInCategoryOrSubcategory",
    url: "{category}/{subcategory}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "Index", subcategory = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

// http://localhost/Car/Ford/ABC123/Explorer
// http://localhost/Car/Ford/ABC123
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Kakel",
    url: "{category}/{subcategory}/{id}/{productName}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "Details", productName = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

// http://localhost/Home/About
// http://localhost/Products/RenderImage/ABC123 (used to render image in details view)
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: How would MVC know what the difference between `/Products/RenderImage/ABC123` and `/Car/Ford/ABC123` is without you explicitly telling it that `Car` is not actually a Controller? Why wouldn't the route be `/Products/Car/Ford/ABC123`?

Comment: I guess I could do a custom one for just `RenderImage`, but that does not solve the `/Home/About`. Maybe what I'm trying to do is not possible? I guess another segment like you said isnt _that_ bad..

Answer (score 0):

you can use the route constraints to solve this problem. let say for your first route  **AllProductsInCategoryOrSubcategory** you can add constraint like this. Here I am using you have only one category at this time that is car.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "AllProductsInCategoryOrSubcategory",
    url: "{category}/{subcategory}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "Index", 
                     subcategory = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new {category = "^car$"}
);
```

Because of this route constraints MVC will select this route when the category name will be **car**.
One important point is you need to add defaults value prior to the route constraints. Because while selecting route MVC will first select default value then will apply constraint.

Comment: That means I have to add a word in the constraint for every category..?

Comment: This was just an example. you can prepare better regular expression as per your need and then you can use that in constraint.